# How to add a `from to` filter for the Products in Category grid

Tags: magento2, category-products, custom-column-grid

I extended this class: `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Produc` to add another column qty. This is how I added the column:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    $this->addColumnAfter('qty', [
        'header' => __('Qty'),
        'index' => 'qty',
        'header_css_class' => 'col-visibility',
        'column_css_class' => 'col-visibility'
    ], 'sku');
    $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
    return $this;
}
```

it works and it displays it like this:

[image]

But I would like to add a FROM-TO instead, like I have for the price or position columns:
[image]

How can I achieve this ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add this :

```
'type' => 'number',
```

so the full code should look like:

```
$this->addColumnAfter('qty', [
    'header' => __('Qty'),
    'index' => 'qty',
    'type' => 'number',
    'header_css_class' => 'col-visibility',
    'column_css_class' => 'col-visibility'
], 'sku');
```

Comment: please consider marking your own answer as valid solution so that others can see it too :)